# symfony: boolean columns not rendering checkbox widgets as checked

Tags: checkbox, symfony1, doctrine, widget

Using Doctrine in symfony 1.4 I have several boolean columns defined (stored as a tinyint in mySQL). The checkbox widgets are always rendering as checked, even when the returned value is '0'. It seems related to [this ticket](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/3996).

Is this a common problem? Is there a workaround?

I can get it working by changing line 70 in sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox to:

```
if (null !== $value && $value !== false && $value !== 0)
```

but I'd rather not alter core symfony files.

Comment: Thanks for raising this issue. I can confirm this is still an issue as of 11.2011. Looked like they may have fixed it in 1.4.15 release but it did not. http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/3996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony unresolved bug, see http://www.devexp.eu/2009/04/23/sfwidgetforminputcheckbox-unchecked-bug/

Your database returns a 0 for a unchecked box but Symfony renders it as checked.

You can patch yourself by editing symfony/lib/widget/sfwidgetforminputcheckbox.class, line 70 (in version 1.4.6), change:

`if (null !== $value && $value !== false)`

in

`if (null !== $value && $value !== false && $value != 0)`

Comment: For any future readers of this solution, be forewarned, you should never change core class behavior, otherwise when you upgrade you will lose your changes, go to production, and wonder why it's not behaving like it used to.

Answer (score 2):

Another hack to resolve this bug without changing the Symfony classes is to set the default value for the field in the database to 0 (unchecked):

```
chk_field: { type: boolean, default: 0 }
```

And in set the widget in the Form.class as follows:

```
$this->setDefault('chk_field', $this->getOption('default'));
```

This should display the 'chk_field' field as 'unchecked' in your form

Comment: I changed it to default: null, and worked without the setDefault option.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in what context you're seeing the problem. I can get the following to work fine:

```
$database_field = '1;0;1;0;1;0;1';
$checked = explode(';', $database_field);
$this->form->getWidget('a_set_of_checkboxes')->setDefault($checked);
```

... the checkboxes with 1's get checked, 0's not.

I'm using "sfWidgetFormChoice" widgets with the attributes "multiple: true" and "expanded: true" so they're not individual checkbox widgets, but rather a single widget that contains an array of checkboxes/values.

Comment: My widget class is sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox because it's just a single field.